# How do I create multiple weighted edges between nodes

Tags: neo4j, py2neo, neo4j.rb

I want to keep all the browse history,

To calculate the behaviour among browsing pages.

So I designed the following graph to show my idea,

As you can see, there are **4 edges** between **page A** and **page B**,

So how could I create the kind of relationships and nodes ?

how could I get the

- average browsing time (**20min**)
- min browsing time
- max browsing time

Any suggestion and ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your design could do with a rework. I'd say the best way is to have a 'Browsing' node in-between the page nodes, which you store the times on. Designing it like you have limits considerably the type of queries which you can perform on your graph

Comment: did you mean each browse request should have a new node ? how does the node represents from pageA to pageB with the duration time. i'm new to neo4j, just couln't understand it.

Comment: The 'Browse' node would have an attribute 'Duration' which would contain the time.  In Cypher you could use create (p1:Page {Name: "Page1"})-[:from]->(b:Browse {Duration: 10})-[:to]->(p2:Page {Name: "Page2"}) return p1,p2

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused.  What does the relationship mean?  Does it represent the amount of time spent on page A before the user browses to page B?

Just going from your model and your goals, maybe something like this would work?

```
MATCH (a:Page)-[r:browsed_to]->(b:Page)
RETURN avg(r.time_spent)
```

For min and max time you could replace `avg` with `min` and `max`

Comment: yes, it is what you mean, so How could I create the kind of relationship between pages ? just create a relationship edge for each browse action ?

Comment: Yeah, you could certainly do that with `MATCH ... CREATE start-[:browsed_to {time_spent: {time_spent_param}}]->end`.  I'm not sure of your use case, but it might be useful instead to have nodes be the visits.  So you could have `(:Visit)-[:NEXT_VISIT]->(:Visit)` and `(:Visit)-[:AT_URL]->(:URL)` where `Visit` nodes would have the `time_spent` and `URL` nodes would have something like a `address` property which has a unique constraint